# Using NonlinearModelFit function with polynomial I have defined

Tags: fitting, data

I have a data set that I wish to write a loop for to fit polynomials to. I want to be able to type in the max order polynomial I want it to calculate the fit for and have it solve each along the way. I will worry about the loop part later, for now the question is how do I set the coefficients in the `NonlinearModelFit` function to solve for the coefficients that I have set in my polynomial definition?

```
data = {{1, 1.1}, {2, 3.9}, {4, 15.7}, {5, 26}}

polynomial[vars_List, n_Integer, coeff_] :=
  #.Array[coeff, Length@#] &@
    DeleteDuplicates[Times @@@ Tuples[Prepend[vars, 1], n]]
(* credit to  user 'March' *)
```

So the input:

```
polynomial[{x}, 2, a]
```

Gives

```
a[1] + x a[2] + x^2 a[3]
```

To get a fit as a quadratic I want to put in:

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, polynomial[{x}, 2, a], {a}, x]
```

Yet this gives an error. What should I put instead of `{a}` in the coefficient argument of the `NonlinearModelFit` function?

Comment: Polynomial models are linear models so one doesn't have to use `NonlinearModelFit`.  For a cubic why not use `LinearModelFit[data, Table[x^i, {i, 3}], x]`?

Answer (score 1):

The list of parameters `{a}` is just one parameter, and is different from list of the parameters contained in your polynomial, which in the case of your example is `{a[1], a[2], a[3]}`.

So the correct syntax for your example would be

```
NonlinearModelFit[data, polynomial[{x}, 2, a], {a[1], a[2], a[3]}, x]
```

and you could generate the parameter list programmatically from a polynomial through

```
Cases[polynomial[{x}, 2, a], a[_], \[Infinity]]
```

or similar.